# jQuery selector click function clarification

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Theres a gap in my understanding that i'd liked filled;

I have a basic jQuery click function like this..

```
 $('.cl').each(function(e)
 {
      alert('works');
      $(this).click(function()
      {
        alert('no works');
      });
 });
```

My HTML is like this:

```
<body>
<div id='c0'>
    <div class='bO cl'>Button</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Basic stuff.

The 'works' alert is fired ok - but with the click function nothing happens - 'no works' is *not* fired.

Also

```
$('.cl').click(function()
{
    alert('help');
});
```

Does not work. Simple stuff i'm sure but i'm missing something.

Why is this?

Comment: Are you running this in the `load` handler?

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/5wB2y/ You do have to click on the div...

Comment: If i understand correctly than yes - the each is located within an init function called by '$(document).ready(function()
{
  init()
});'

Comment: Something must be wrong with the setup as it works fine as-is in a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U7tJt/ Try running your setup in Chrome with the F12 debug window open and see if you get any errors.

Comment: @boomshanka you must make sure that your div Button is already in the page, if this only become to existance after an ajax call, at the moment you load the page the Jquery dont find those "Button" and you have to use the CED_B approach, using delegate events ($.on/off)

Comment: As @boomshanka implies, there may be a lot more to your code than the small piece you have shown us. Please show the entire relevant code/HTML

Comment: Thanks for all your help - the answer is i'm an idiot that was clicking the wrong button. If its any consolation i did learn something but really sorry for wasting all your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to make sure is that you run the event handler once the DOM and jQuery are initialized, which is by doing this:

```
$(function() {

   $('.cl').click(function()
   {
      alert('help');
   });

});
```

Also alternatively, if your `cl` is loaded after the fact such as by an Ajax call you can alternativley do this

```
$("body").on("click", ".cl", function() {
   // Your code here
})
```

This registers the click event with the body but only gets dispatched if the actual target is of type `cl`.

Comment: The OP has already confirmed that this is the case. See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283565/jquery-selector-click-function-clarification/18283600#comment26822205_18283565).